# uppered dna transcription with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, dna-sequence

This is the code I have to achieve my objective as stated in the title. The problem I seem to have right now is the second line of code. The moment I added it the program stopped working without giving me an error. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
seqDNA = input()
seqDNA = seqDNA.upper()
comp = ''
for c in seqDNA:
    if c == 'a':
        comp = comp + 'u'
    elif c == 't':
        comp = comp + 'a'
    elif c == 'g':
        comp = comp + 'c'
    elif c == 'c':
        comp = comp + 'g'
print(comp)
```

Comment: What do you mean with *second line*? `seqDNA = seqDNA.upper()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior since **you check uppercase characters against lowercase ones**.

After `seqDNA = seqDNA.upper()`, your string contains *uppercase* characters. For instance:

```
seqDNA = 'UGCGGCGAATATTT'
```

If we now iterate through it with `for c in seqDNA`, `c` will contain an uppercase character (i.e. `'C'`). Now if you compare `c == 'C'`, you compare `'c' == 'C'`, and those are **not** equal.

So you should modify the tests to:

```
seqDNA = input()
seqDNA = seqDNA.upper()
comp = ''
for c in seqDNA:
    if c == 'A':
        comp = comp + 'u'
    elif c == 'T':
        comp = comp + 'a'
    elif c == 'G':
        comp = comp + 'c'
    elif c == 'C':
        comp = comp + 'g'
print(comp)
```

That being said, your code works inefficient: first of all the sequence of `elif` statements is expensive, and furthermore you perform a `comp = comp + 'u'` operation. String appending runs in *O(n)*, making this algorithm *O(<sup>2</sup>)*.

We can improve it by **using a dictionary**, and **use `''.join(..)` over appending manually.

```
seqDNA = input()
seqDNA = seqDNA.upper()
trans = {
    'A': 'u',
    'T': 'a',
    'G': 'c',
    'C': 'g'
}
comp = ''.join(trans[c] for c in seqDNA)
print(comp)
```

This will raise a `KeyError` in case the `seqDNA` contains a character, other than `'A'`, `'T'`, `'G'`, and `'C'`. Which seems to me as reasonable behavior. In case you simply want to *ignore* these characters, you can use `.get(..,'')` over `[c]`:

```
seqDNA = input()
seqDNA = seqDNA.upper()
trans = {
    'A': 'u',
    'T': 'a',
    'G': 'c',
    'C': 'g'
}
comp = ''.join(trans.get(c,'') for c in seqDNA)
print(comp)
```

Comment: I understand and thank you for the code optimization altough I'm not yet comfortable with dictionaries. 
What I should have done was , and I don't know I didn't remember, was to simply upper in the end:
     comp = comp.upper()